# Why has my inner tube enlarged after moving from bicycle to repair

Tags: tire, repair

I got two punctures in my front inner tuner of my bike and when I have gone to reassemble, the inner tube appears to have stretched a significant amount and no longer fits along the rim of the bike, not sure why this has happened and is there anything to be done to fix this?

Comment: How deflated is the tube when you're putting it back?  If it has any significant pressure at all it will expand in circumference as well as diameter.  You don't want it *completely* flat but it should barely hold its shape.

Comment: After I patch a tube, I leave it inflated overnight with ~5 psi in it.  This significantly stretches the butyl rubber, to the point reinstalling it immediately is a challenge.  Perhaps 25% larger diameter. So I roll up the tested tube and put it in my on-bike toolbag.  By the time I need it, the rubber has reverted to a normal size and its easier to re-fit.

Answer (score 5):

You can just stuff it into the tire. It will be fine.

1. Get one of the tire's beads on the rim.
2. Put a little air in the tube so it holds its shape.
3. Put the tube's valve through the valve hole and work the rest of the tube inside the tire.
4. Work the other bead onto the rim. As you get close to the end, you may need to deflate the tube. Make sure none of the tube is pinched between the tire and rim.

Comment: "stuffing it in" works to a point, but too much tube is asking for a zig-zag fold or a tube pinched in the bead.